# My VPS has been shut down now again for the second time for TOS violations email spam

Tags: apache, joomla2.5, joomla1.5, vps, joomla3.0

My VPS has been shut down now again for the second time for TOS violations, and I really need some help. I have been battling with my server being attacked for over a year now. Most of my sites are running Joomla ranging from 1.5 installs (which cannot be upgraded because the customers have declined the upgrade, really its only 2 sites running 1.5) to 3.1 installs. I am not sure where the vulnerability is. i have gone through all of my scripts and enabled captcha, changed my admin passwords, changed my database passwords, and checked my extensions against joomla's vulnerable extension list. what else can i set up to prevent this from happening? THis is about my 5th attack in a year, and about my 5th time tightening the belt on everything just to have my efforts fail....grrrrr

Comment: Security questions like these have a better home at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would definitely look at dividing things if you can. I would recommend finding a way to get each account on a different account so that the vulnerable site will get attacked and hurt without affecting every install. This would make it a lot easier to know which site causes the issues. Then you know who HAS to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

We dealt with the same problem earlier this year. First, you need to look through your log files to determine which site(s) are getting attacked. My guess would be that the sites being hit at 1.5 sites, without exception that was the case on our servers. If that is the case, then those sites need to be let go. If they don't want to upgrade, they need to take their sites elsewhere. Simple as that. You cannot risk your other sites and email blacklists due to customers that don't want to upgrade. We don't allow J1.5 on our servers any more.

Comment: Only a few days ago I found out about Phil Tayloer's offering http://myjoomla.com/ which I'd like to recommend - he's put a lot of effort and experience into it. (I'm not affiliated or whatever - just a happy user...)